# Easy way to identify button and auto load its target

Tags: c#

I have this portion of code

```
            przyciski[i] = new Button();
            przyciski[i].Visible = false;
            przyciski[i].Name = "przycisk" + i;
            przyciski[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(ButtonClickHandler);
```

which is describing dynamicly created button, and this eventhandler underneath the program

```
    private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        if(btn.Name == "przycisk1")
            {
                //Open specific JPEG in external aplication 
            }

    }
```

Is there any quicker way to identify button and its target?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option. If you're going to perform a different piece of code for every button anyway, why bother giving them a name and then having to detect the name in the click event?

Just create your buttons, and then specify what each should do.

```
var przyciski = new List<Button>();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    przyciski.Add(new Button { Visible = false });

przyciski[0].Click += (s, e) => { /* Do something */ };
przyciski[1].Click += (s, e) => { /* Open specific JPEG in external aplication */ };
przyciski[2].Click += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("You clicked button 2."); };
przyciski[3].Click += (s, e) => { };
przyciski[4].Click += (s, e) => { };
```

Comment: This should be the answer in my opinion. Set different events to all needed buttons (or set the same if needed) and if they have something in common just create a method that does it and call it in every click event.

Comment: Great! this is easiest solution!

Answer (score 1):

If `przyciski` is an instance variable, you can check for reference equality:

```
private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (sender == przycisk[1])
    {
        //Open specific JPEG in external aplication 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```